# Matrix to image conversion in HALCON

Tags: halcon

I have been trying to convert a matrix to an image in Halcon. So far I have only managed to do with set_grayval in a for loop through all pixels. Can someone suggest a better way to do it?
Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
get_domain (Image, Domain)
get_region_points (Domain, Rows, Columns)
set_grayval (Image, Rows, Columns, GrayvalValues)
```